# How to write a config in UTF-8 in Bukkit

Tags: java, bukkit, snakeyaml

In my bukkit plugin (1.8.8), I want to save a configuration file on my bukkit server disk with my plugin. In many servers it works but in others, it does not work.

I think that I can use an OutputStreamWriter with the SnakeYaml API but is there anything in Bukkit API to do this ? It will be easier ^^

Thank you for your help !

EDIT : `FileConfiguration#save(file)` can do this but not every time because there is : `UTF8_OVERRIDE && !UTF_BIG ? Charsets.UTF_8 : Charset.defaultCharset()` to choose the Charset.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stackoverflow.
Spigot does have an ConfigurationAPI. [Introduction to ConfigurationAPI](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/creating-a-config-file/) The Wiki holds an very good Tutorial how to use the new ConfigurationAPI. Advantageously you dont need to care about charsets in files and formatting.

Alternatively you could have a look at **Properties** from Standard Java Library [Properties Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Comment: Ohhh, I forgot to write that I need to force Charest to utf-8 ^^'. I know how to use the normal way ^^ If I use an OutputStreamWriter with the Utf-8 Charest, I don't have problem ^^